# How do I fold code for comment blocks inside method blocks in the Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, formatting, ide, comments, folding

How can I fold comment blocks inside method blocks to be folded (outlined), just like methods and regions, etc.?

```
sample_method_or_Class()
{
 /* I'd like to fold this
  * comment block
  */
}
/* The same way I can fold this one
 * outside the code block.
 */
```

Does Eclipse support functionality like Visual Studio does  like ([How do I fold code for comment blocks inside method blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5922763/how-do-i-fold-code-for-comment-blocks-inside-method-blocks)) ?

Comment: In what language?

Comment: My particular case is with Eclipse Photon for Java, I had hoped however any solution would be common across Eclipse editions for different languages.

Comment: That's not really how Eclipse is structured. It hosts different editors in the workbench according to a a few simple Java Interfaces, so the implementation details and feature set can and will vary by language.

Comment: Comments generally are before the member (type, method, or field) on which they are referring. In your example, however, nothing comes after the comments and therefore the comments are treated as commented out code that cannot be folded. Maybe you can describe why you want this? Maybe there is an alternative solution or workaround (e. g. Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down to go to previous/next member).

Comment: It is precisely  commenting  out blocks of code, for unit testing,  incrementally varying the tests applied on each build, and preserving old implementations in the source until a new implementation is tested, rather than using version control for smaller personal projects.

Comment: @Miami_Programmer I guess [this plug-in does what you want](https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/EclipseFolding) (see [here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6947590/6505250)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such support in Eclipse, unfortunately. There is [a request for this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=258965) though, reported in 2008 with only 10 votes, so I would not expect it implemented any time soon.

Mentions of an Eclipse folding plugin called [Coffee Bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895205/can-anyone-confirm-if-coffee-bytes-works-with-eclipse-oxygen) can be found, but most links are broken. Looks like latest Eclipse versions are not supported and the project looks discontinued.

**Update:**

As indicated by [howlger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6505250/howlger) in the comment below, [EclipseFolding](https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/EclipseFolding) plugin is alive and well. I've tested it now, installed it via `Help / Install new software... / Add...` using its update site:

- https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/EclipseFolding/raw/master/com.cb.platsupp.site

After Eclipse restart I got little red squares indicating folding capability for both comment scenarios from the question:

[image]

Comment: Here is a [fork of Coffee Bytes](https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/EclipseFolding). See my old comment above.